# How to work with deeply nested JSON (extracting results and renaming keys) with Jenkins Groovy?

Tags: json, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am newbie to groovy and programming overall (system administration background), so I need some help in a non-standard case (for me). I want not only the solution(s) itself, but rather a bit of understanding on how to work with JSON's in Groovy (particularly, Jenkins Groovy).

What I want to achieve: from several basic "big" JSON inputs (they are scanner results):

1. remove all unnecessary key-value pairs,
2. extract from deeply inside of "big" JSON several required key-value pairs;
3. rename extracted keys (there is a map of renames);
4. put all extracted and renamed key-value pairs into a final JSON.

Enhardening:

a) First scanner has 5 of required key-value pairs, second - six (see below keys rename map) - resulting JSON should have empty values for "Path" keys;

b) Each scanner results is multiple files to work with;

c) Some keys and values are written in CAPITAL or small literals, but they all must be renamed to comply with "First capital letter only", e.g. "HIGH" must become "High" and "severity" must become "Severity";

d) Final JSON must be sorted and have duplicates removed (two fields are uniqueness criteria).

I will provide the examples:

"Big" JSON:

```
    "SchemaVersion": 2,
    "ArtifactName": "",
    "ArtifactType": "container_image",
    "Metadata": {
        "OS": {
            "Family": "suse linux enterprise server",
            "Name": "15.3"
        },
        "ImageID": "sha256:qweqwe",
        "DiffIDs": [
            "sha256:yyy",
            "sha256:xxx"
        ],
        "ImageConfig": {
            "architecture": "amd64",
            "created": "2021-12-17T04:29:17.322895374Z",
            "docker_version": "19.03.15",
            "history": [
                {
                    "created": "2021-10-11T00:16:48Z",
                    "created_by": "KIWI 9.23.20"
                },
                {
                    "created": "2021-12-17T04:29:17Z",
                    "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY --chown=eeee in /app/ "
                }
            ],
            "os": "linux",
            "rootfs": {
                "type": "layers",
                "diff_ids": [
                    "sha256:zzz",
"sha256:ttt"
                ]
            },
            "config": {
                "Entrypoint": [
                    "bash",
                    "/app/run.sh"
                ],
                "Env": [
                    "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                    "ANT_HOME=/opt/ant"
                ],
                "Image": "sha256:www",
                "Labels": {
                    "product-version": "3.37.0-5",
                    "common_base_os": "3.37.0-5"
                },
                "User": "jboss",
                "WorkingDir": "/app/jboss"
            }
        }
    },
    "Results": [
        {
            "Target": "(suse linux enterprise server 15.3)",
            "Class": "os-pkgs",
            "Type": "suse linux enterprise server",
            "Vulnerabilities": [
                {
                    "VulnerabilityID": "SUSE-SU-2021:3454-1",
                    "PkgName": "krb5",
                    "InstalledVersion": "1.16.3-3.21.1",
                    "FixedVersion": "1.16.3-3.24.1",
                    "Layer": {
                        "DiffID": "sha256:e5f75917669c6b16d435af5011b1ac5c13f38aa01145ce44e2ffdf59fdfde693"
                    },
                    "Title": "Security update for krb5",
                    "Description": "This update for krb5 fixes the following issues:\n\n- CVE-2021-37750: Fixed KDC null pointer dereference via a FAST inner body that lacks a server field (bsc#1189929).\n",
                    "Severity": "MEDIUM",
                    "References": [
                        "https://bugzilla.suse.com/1189929",
                        "https://lists.suse.com/pipermail/sle-security-updates/2021-October/009605.html",
                        "https://www.suse.com/security/cve/CVE-2021-37750/",
                        "https://www.suse.com/support/security/rating/",
                        "https://www.suse.com/support/update/announcement/2021/suse-su-20213454-1/"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "VulnerabilityID": "CVE-2014-3530",
                    "PkgName": "org.picketlink:picketlink-common",
                    "InstalledVersion": "2.5.5.SP12-redhat-00009",
                    "FixedVersion": "2.6.1.Final",
                    "Layer": {
                        "DiffID": "sha256:5e14bc0aa82e004d3f2ef075678f65fa60fac03cb7669803f676abc9f71c04c1"
                    },
                    "SeveritySource": "nvd",
                    "PrimaryURL": "https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2014-3530",
                    "Title": "PicketLink: XXE via insecure DocumentBuilderFactory usage",
                    "Description": "The org.picketlink.common.util.DocumentUtil.getDocumentBuilderFactory method in PicketLink, as used in Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform (JBEAP) 5.2.0 and 6.2.4, expands entity references, which allows remote attackers to read arbitrary code and possibly have other unspecified impact via unspecified vectors, related to an XML External Entity (XXE) issue.",
                    "Severity": "HIGH",
                    "CweIDs": [
                        "CWE-200"
                    ],
                    "CVSS": {
                        "nvd": {
                            "V2Vector": "AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:P/I:P/A:P",
                            "V2Score": 7.5
                        },
                        "redhat": {
                            "V2Vector": "AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:P/I:P/A:P",
                            "V2Score": 7.5
                        }
                    },
                    "References": [
                        "http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2014-0883.html",
                        "http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2014-0884.html",
                        "http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2014-0885.html",
                        "http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2014-0886.html",
                        "http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2015-0091.html",
                        "http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2015-0675.html",
                        "http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2015-0720.html",
                        "http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2015-0765.html",
                        "http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2015-1888.html",
                        "http://secunia.com/advisories/60047",
                        "http://secunia.com/advisories/60124",
                        "http://www.securitytracker.com/id/1030607",
                        "https://bugzilla.redhat.com/CVE-2014-3530",
                        "https://exchange.xforce.ibmcloud.com/vulnerabilities/94700"
                    ],
                    "PublishedDate": "2014-07-22T20:55:00Z",
                    "LastModifiedDate": "2018-01-05T02:29:00Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Required keys to be saved:

```
"VulnerabilityID",
"PkgName",
"InstalledVersion",
"FixedVersion",
"Severity"
```

Keys rename map:

```
renameMap: [scanner1: ["VulnerabilityID": "ID", "PkgName": "Package", "InstalledVersion": "Installed version", "FixedVersion": "Fixed", "Severity": "Severity"],
scanner2 : ["vuln": "ID", "name": "Package", "vers": "Installed version", "fix": "Fixed", "severity": "Severity", "impact_path": "Path"]]
```

Target JSON (example):

```
{
    "Vulnerabilities": [
        {
            "ID": "SUSE-SU-2021:3454-1",
            "Package": "krb5",
            "Installed Version": "1.16.3-3.21.1",
            "Fixed": "1.16.3-3.24.1",
            "Severity": "Medium",
            "Path": ""
        },
        {
            "ID": "CVE-2021-23463",
            "Package": "com.h2database:h2",
            "Installed Version": "1.4.190",
            "Fixed": "2.0.202",
            "Severity": "Critical",
            "Path": "/usr/log/bin/serum_exec" 
        }
    ]
}
```

I am definite noob in working with multi-level mappings and JSON's.
And if each task separately is not very hard, when they are put all together, I hardly understand even where to start.

Thanks all in advance for any help / answers.

EDIT : ADDED : PIPELINE EXAMPLE (Logic)

```
renameMap: [scanner1: ["VulnerabilityID": "ID", "PkgName": "Package", "InstalledVersion": "Installed version", "FixedVersion": "Fixed", "Severity": "Severity"],
scanner2 : ["vuln": "ID", "name": "Package", "vers": "Installed version", "fix": "Fixed", "severity": "Severity", "impact_path": "Path"]]

pipeline {
    stages {
        stage 'run scanner 1' {
            steps {
                script {
                    jobResult = runJob scan/scanner1
                    scan_artifacts1 = getArtifacts "${jobResult.absoluteUrl}/*.json"
                }
            }
        }
        stage 'run scanner 2' {
            steps {
                script {
                    jobResult = runJob scan/scanner2
                    scan_artifacts2 = getArtifacts "${jobResult.absoluteUrl}/*.json"
                }
            }
        }
        stage 'aggregate results' {
            steps {
                script {
                    scan_artifacts1.each {file ->
                        raw_input = readJSON file: file
                        1) removing unneeded key-values
                        should I use output = raw_input.remove() ?
                        2) extract required key-value pairs
                        output.Results.Vulnerabilities.each {} ?
                        3) + 4) rename keys and put into final JSON
                        should it be like
                        output.each { k, v ->
                            if renameMap.scanner1.contains(k) {
                                k = renameMap.scanner1.k(value)
                            }
                            result_file.put(k,v)
                        }
                    }
                    scan_artifacts2.each {file ->
                        raw_input = readJSON file: file
                        1) removing unneeded key-values
                        2) extract required key-value pairs
                        3) + 4) rename keys and put into final JSON
                        should it be like
                        output.each { k, v ->
                            if renameMap.scanner2.contains(k) {
                                k = renameMap.scanner2.k(value)
                            }
                            result_file.add(k,v)
                        }
                    }
                    raw_result_file = result_file
                    5) remove duplicates (fields "ID" and "Package" are uniqueness criteria). Never did this before.
                    6) sort by field "ID"
                    uniq_sorted_results_file
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does not matter if you are inside jenkins or in plain groovy - the result of parsing is the nested Map/List/Simpletype values. groovy+json basics see here: https://groovy-lang.org/json.html  but in jenking you are using readJSON to parse and writeJSON to build/format data to json string. you have to provide code and clear issue in your question then somebody could help you.

Comment: @daggett, I have updated the question with pipeline "example", containing logic, steps and my questions inside of it. Thanks for attention to question.

I have read the basics, but it's hard currently for me to go deeper than single-level mappings or simple JSONs.